# Auto Downloading a Git Commit with Windows

Tags: git, gitlab, githooks

I have a git repo with hundreds of files in it. One of those files is a Powershell Profile. I also have two windows servers where I want that Powershell Profile to be updated.

Does anyone have a good way of automatically updating the file whenever a git commit is done? I don't want to pull down the whole repo, I just want the single file. I feel like the best way to do it would be to do it with a git hook, but most of the examples I've found just download the whole repo.

Comment: You can always checkout a single file just use `--` before its name to indicate it is a path, not revision.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it by hook, but pull just a single file.

```
git fetch <remote>
git checkout FETCH_HEAD -- <file>
```

> If you want to check out all C source files out of the index, you can
>   say
>
> `$ git checkout -- '*.c'` Note the quotes around `*.c`. The file `hello.c`
>   will also be checked out, even though it is no longer in the working
>   tree, because the file globbing is used to match entries in the index
>   (not in the working tree by the shell).
>
> If you have an unfortunate branch that is named `hello.c`, this step
>   would be confused as an instruction to switch to that branch. You
>   should instead write:
>
> `$ git checkout -- hello.c`
>
> https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout

**Example**

There is a documentation about BitBucket Webhooks: https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Manage+Webhooks

There is a gitlab screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Where is your repository located?

Comment: It's a gitlab repo. I want to download the updates to two windows servers.

Comment: @DanSolomon You could call it on all type webhook or only `Repository
Push`.